# Product attributes and label attribute group

Tags: product, magento-1.9, attributes

I would like to show the various attributes divided into groups as created in the set of attributes, such as

- general

  - attribute 1
  - attribute 2
  - ...
- other info

  - attribute 1
  - attribute 2
  - ...

How do I retrieve the attribute groups and their labels?

or is there a module to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$attributeGroupCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_group_collection');

foreach ($attributeGroupCollection as $attributeGroup) {
  echo "\n\nGroup Name: " . $attributeGroup->getAttributeGroupName();
  echo "\nGroup ID: " . $attributeGroup->getAttributeGroupId();

  $attributeCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
    ->setAttributeGroupFilter($attributeGroup->getAttributeGroupId());

  foreach($attributeCollection as $attribute) {
    echo "\n\t Attribute Frontend Label: " . $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
    echo "\n\t Attribute Name: " . $attribute->getName();
  }
}
```

You get:

```
...
Group Name: Design
Group ID: 37
         Attribute Fontend Label: Custom Design
         Attribute Name: custom_design
         Attribute Fontend Label: Active From
         Attribute Name: custom_design_from
         Attribute Fontend Label: Active To
         Attribute Name: custom_design_to
         Attribute Fontend Label: Custom Layout Update
         Attribute Name: custom_layout_update
         Attribute Fontend Label: Page Layout
         Attribute Name: page_layout
         Attribute Fontend Label: Display Product Options In
         Attribute Name: options_container

Group Name: Recurring Profile
Group ID: 38
         Attribute Fontend Label: Enable Recurring Profile
         Attribute Name: is_recurring
         Attribute Fontend Label: Recurring Profile
         Attribute Name: recurring_profile

Group Name: Images
Group ID: 39
         Attribute Fontend Label: Base Image
         Attribute Name: image
         Attribute Fontend Label: Small Image
         Attribute Name: small_image
         Attribute Fontend Label: Thumbnail
         Attribute Name: thumbnail
         Attribute Fontend Label: Media Gallery
         Attribute Name: media_gallery
         Attribute Fontend Label: Image Gallery
         Attribute Name: gallery
         Attribute Fontend Label: Swatch Color
         Attribute Name: swatch_color

Group Name: Meta Information
Group ID: 40
         Attribute Fontend Label: Meta Title
         Attribute Name: meta_title
         Attribute Fontend Label: Meta Keywords
         Attribute Name: meta_keyword
         Attribute Fontend Label: Meta Description
         Attribute Name: meta_description
...
```

You can then build upon this to get attribute values/options as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Oleg, your suggest show all attibute, but I want show only some group set of attribute.

Comment: @Joso then simply filter the collection by what groups you want to show :)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I'm not a programmer, I only know a few commands / scripts php and html and I could not do what you described. 

But I thought if the various attributes can be retrieved in some way in the file .phtml without having to modify the php strength relative to that function. 

for example: <? php echo $ _helper-> productAttribute ($ product, ($ _product-> getDescription2 ()), 'description2')?>

Comment: I want to show attribute group name in product page, can you tell me where should I copy this code? thanks